# How to discover test files whose filename starts with Unicode by TestLoader?

Tags: python, unit-testing, unicode

Python package `app` contains three files:

- `__init__.py`
- `A試驗.py`
- `試驗.py`

Code:

```
suite=unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('app',pattern='*.py')
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

I want to load `A試驗.py` and `試驗.py`, but this only discovers the `A試驗.py` file.

Is it spec or bug?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linut Mint 17 with python 3.4

Comment: I have not checked by wonder if `pattern=ur'*.py'` will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `TestLoader` considers a valid module name is limited:

```
# From unittest/loader.py
VALID_MODULE_NAME = re.compile(r'[_a-z]\w*\.py$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

It looks deliberate (otherwise, `r'\w+\.py$'` would be used), but I don't know what the reason for requiring ASCII for the first letter is. It might be worth reporting as a bug if no one here provides an explanation.